# I want to schedule task at particular time using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests

I want to schedule JMeter so that it will run a test thread automatically after every 1 or 2 hrs.

Comment: You should specify what you tried to do so far, and give an example of your workflow. Otherwise this question is too broad.

Comment: Hello                                                                                                              Actually I am trying to load testing my app by setting to automatic Start  and end test run time in Scheduler.(Not manually click run Button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can schedule your test with the help of windows Task Scheduler

```
1. Create a batch file write below code,do required modification
```

> D:
>   cd Software\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin
>   jmeter -n -t D:\test.jmx -l D:\results.jtl

```
2.open Task Scheduler, create a task, add the batch file path and schedule
  your task on the base your requirement
```

[image]

Hope that will help full for you

Answer (score 4):

There are at least 2 options:

1. JMeter test can be run in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t /path/to/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/results.jtl
   ```

   If you put above line into a shell script file should be able to use your operating system scheduling mechanism to run it as you need:

   - [Windows Task Scheduler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html) - for MS Windows Family
   - [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html) - for MacOSX
   - [cron](http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/) - for Linux/Unix
2. You can set Loop Count to "Forever" on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level and put a [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) to sleep desired number of time between test iterations.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri.. That's what I was looking for